# How to access an object from a different thread without conflict?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a thread named fetchImage that runs startFetch() method, which is

```
     for (int i = 0; !stopFetching && i < 2000; i++) {
      control.fetchImage().Save("Fetch_Image\\fetchedFile" + fileName + ".JPG", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            fileName++;
        //Thread.Sleep(800);
            Console.WriteLine("Filename :" + fileName);
```

control is another class that has fetchImage() method:

```
 return (System.Drawing.Bitmap)mainForm.imageTemp.Clone();
```

`mainForm` is a form that has Image variable named imageTemp. Now `startFetch()` runs fine when I have `Thread.Sleep(800)` but it gives me that error without the sleep. Here is the stack trace of the error

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  Message=Object is currently in use elsewhere.
  Source=System.Drawing
  StackTrace:
       at System.Drawing.Image.Clone()
       at KiPNi.Control.fetchImage() in F:\CMPS285\285-fall10-5\Final working code\WindowsFormsApplication7\Control.cs:line 65
       at KiPNi.Form4.startFetch() in F:\CMPS285\285-fall10-5\Final working code\WindowsFormsApplication7\Form4.cs:line 80
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

I do not know much about threads (although I tried after encountering this problem).

> How do I get access to the image from the fetchImage thread?

Comment: You really need to post the code of what `fetchImage` is doing. A resource (aka file) is being locked by another thread.

Comment: A bitmap can be used by only one thread at a time.  We can see your worker thread accessing it, that's the code that bombed.  It is also being used on another thread.  That's probably the main thread, trying to paint the bitmap.  I'd guess you got it in a PictureBox.  There's no real fix for that other than not showing it in a PB or creating your own control so that you can use the lock keyword around the Graphics.DrawImage() call.

Comment: @SilverNinja, sorry i did not specify correctly: fetchImage() is just returning clone of image `imageTemp` from mainForm.
 `return (System.Drawing.Bitmap)mainForm.imageTemp.Clone();`

Comment: @HansPassant I do understand the concept you are talking about. I think it applies to other GUI components also ( A calling thread cannot change values of another threads instances). I am not using `Graphics.DrawImage()`but System.Drawing.Image object (Visual C#).

Comment: What I cannot get is that it works fine if I do `Thread.sleep()`. However if i do that, the images I send to server per second will be less compared to when I loop it without discontinuity. And you are right about imageTemp, `imageTemp = pictureBox1.Image;` where pictureBox1 is referenced to webcam video. @Hans Passant

Comment: Code working with Thread.Sleep() is dumb luck - reducing the chance of a race condition doesn't mean it's gone :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of *pulling* data from the processing thread, see if it's possible to *push* data from the UI thread when there's a frame update - that way, you can **possibly** avoid locking; if you can create a clone of the image data, you avoid sharing the object between threads.

You really only should be invoking methods on UI controls from the main thread anyway ([Control.BeginInvoke()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke.aspx) exists, but it's better trying to modify your design to avoid it, if possible).

Comment: I understand what you are saying. The reason I created Clone() of imageTemp was to avoid such conflict `return (System.Drawing.Bitmap)mainForm.imageTemp.Clone();`. Right now I have implemented a `Forms.Timer()` which ticks every 1/2 second. So far there is no bug. But I really want to fetch more frames per second (continuous if possible). I would really appreciate a code to demonstrate what you are saying. Thanks for your help

Comment: The problem is you're calling the Clone method in your other thread - this can clash with control being updated in the main UI thread. Try having the UI thread do the Clone, and pass it off to a worker thread - push instead of pull processing.